# How to handle letting users know I'm waiting on a response from DB in Redux?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I'd like to send data to server and wait to response. To do that, I'd like my Redux action method to fire instant object action first, making my UI showing that its waiting, and the thunk action then, after server response. Can I do this using single action method? And generally, what's the best practice for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually handle this is by having statuses in your state like so:

```
const initialState = {
  isPendingDBResponse: false,
  errorFromDB: "",
  data: [...] // any data sent back from the DB if it's needed
}
```

Then whatever component you have would just use something like a ternary operator to handle the different statuses:

```
import React from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ isPendingDBResponse, errorFromDB, data }) => (
  <div>
    {(isPendingDBResponse)
      ? <p>Waiting on DB...</p>
      : (errorFromDB)
      ? <p>{errorFromDB}</p>
      : <p>Everything was sent successfully</p> // Display any data here if needed
    }
  </div>
)

const mapStateToProps ({ reducerName }) => {

  const { isPendingDBResponse, errorFromDB, data } = reducerName;

  return {
    isPendingDBResponse,
    errorFromDB,
    data
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Hmm, my question was more about how to do this using actions. Can I have single action called `submit` that sets the flag and waits for the response at the same time?

Comment: @KarolSelak absolutely! You can use redux-thunk for asynchronous state updates. I made a plugin called [redux-honey](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-honey) that makes it far easier to work with asynchronous redux state changes

Comment: I am using thunk now, as I mentioned. I'd just like to do two things at once: one using thunk and second the classic way.